# Best way to specify autowire candidate for profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, component-scan

In my spring boot application for some interfaces I have several implementations (usually "main implementation" and "implementation for local testing") which I use with different profiles. I know several options to tell spring to use specific implementation.

1. Add `@Profile`/`@Conditional` to class annotated with `@Component`. Pros: easy. Cons: I don't like the fact that information about profiles are scattered across components.
2. Remove `@Component` annotation from implementation and instantiate components in profile-specific `@Configuration` (`@Bean SomeService() { return new DefaultSomeService(); }`). Pros: more code required. Cons. All profile-specific components are located in one place.
3. Exclude `@Component` from `@ComponentScan` (by adding explicit custom annotation `@IgnoreComponentScan` into implementation to prevent ambiguity) and instantiate components in profile-specific @Configuration. Close to second option, but gives more clarity to component (we can keep `@Repository`/`@Service` annotations)

Are there other options? Which way is more appropriate?

Comment: IMHO the 2nd approach is the 'cleanest one'  and the most versatile.
the third one might surprise other people joining your project (and raise stackoverflow questions: 'why the heck my @Component annotation does not work...;)

Comment: BTW I'm not @Autowire fun... and prefer to have dependencies listed explicitely even if more code needed...

Comment: @Maciej updated my question. We can create custom annotation ```@IgnoreComponentScan``` and put it behind ```@Component```. So people would not be surprised.

Comment: For my taste that changes nothing - but it's just my opinion... you just have more annotation hell ;) I prefer to have everything strictly defined in one place (well you can have base class with common components for tests and only overwrite what is necessary in your derived test `@Configuration` using `@Primary` annotation)
But that is just my opinion as I said I don't like any 'magic' autowiring as it makes finding root issue causes usually more difficult in the maintenance...